# How to install different font series files in Latex to compile with pdftex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, opentype, otftotfm

I have a problem with compiling my otf "Thesis" font. I have different font families like `TheSerif`, `TheSans` and `TheMix`. Every font family consists of different font series for example bold, italic, regular, caps etc. How is it possible to combine these font series with the `autoinst`? If I try to run `autoinst TheSerif-5-Regular.otf TheSerif-5-RegularCaps` I just get this:

> [ERROR] I failed to parse all fonts in a unique way; presumably some fonts have unusual widths, weights or shapes.

I have already managed to install the individual font families but without caps and expert. I can't use caps etc. because I'm not able to combine the font series for example caps with regular. You can see the available files in the figures. If I compile I always get errors like

> Font shape LY1/cmtt/m/n' undefined(Font) using LY1/ptm/m/n' instead

because the caps etc. are missing.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{TheSerif}   % caps missing
\usepackage{TheSans}    % same here
\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}                           
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}                      

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: font series[1]
[image: font families[2]]

Comment: the warning you show is unrelated to caps or your thesis font family, it says computer modern typewriter is unknown and is being substituted by times roman (that seems rather odd). for the rest, it would be (much) easier to use an otf font from luatex or xetex, do you have a particular need for pdftex? but if you do, use fontenc earlier to declare LY1 encoding, and then basically you will need to hand wwrite the lytheseserf-?.fd files to match the latex NFSS font combinations to your generated file names.

Comment: @David Carlisle can you give an example? I tried already with different kind of codes in my LY1TheSerif.fd file for expample: \DeclareFontShape{LY1}{TheSerif-TLF}{regular}{n}{
      <-> \TheSerif@@scale TheSerif-RegularCaps-tlf-ly1
}{}'

Comment: hard to give examples as I have no idea what font names you have or where `\TheSerif@@scale` etc, butthe one you show would be used if your document had `\fontencoding{LY1}\fontfamily{TheSerif-TLF}\fontseries{regular}\fontshape{n}\selectfont`  so using a non standard series name (would normally just be `m`) butOK as long as your document macros use that name.

Comment: Next question: why is your font encoding `LY1`? Should it not be `T1`? Ok, and further ones: Have you tried [otfinst](https://github.com/nschloe/otfinst)? Have you considered XeTeX or LuaTeX?

Comment: I have the same problems if I use T1. I havent tried otfinst yet. Is it more reliable than autoinst?

Comment: I tried otfinst but I always get the error message: invalid syntax print "%s (TTF)" % filename. I didn't change anything in the script...

Comment: I'd like to repeat this question by @DavidCarlisle: "do you have a particular need for pdftex?" Maybe I missed an answer, but luatex or xetex would be **much** easier to use with OTF fonts.